# No data from connection to port 6000 after Java update version 8.25 on the client side

Tags: java, tcp, applet, connection, port

I have a device with an Apache webserver, and an Applet which connects to port 6000 on that device.

If I load the Applet from my computer with Java version 7.65 then everything works fine.

If I load the Applet from my laptop with Java version 8.25 then I can open the Applet, which makes a connection to port 6000, but it doesn't receive any data from it.

Before I updated Java on my laptop to 8.25 everything worked fine from that laptop as well.

The class I made to connect is:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class tcp
{
    private PrintWriter mwriteServer;
    private BufferedReader mbufServer;
    private Socket msckServer;

    public tcp()
    {
    }

    public void connectVri(URL urlLocal)
    {
        int intOK=0;
        String strLocal = urlLocal.getHost();
        //connect to local ip
        intOK = connectToServer(strLocal,6000);
        if (intOK!=1)
        {
            System.out.println("Failed to connect to : " + strLocal.toString());
        }
    }

    private int connectToServer(String url, int intPort)
    {
        try
        {
            msckServer = new Socket(url,intPort);
            InputStream inStream = msckServer.getInputStream();
            mbufServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
            OutputStream outStream = msckServer.getOutputStream();
            mwriteServer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outStream));
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public int getState()
    {
        if (msckServer!=null)
        {
            if (msckServer.isConnected())
            {
                return 7;
            } else if (msckServer.isClosed())
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void sendCmd(String strCmd)
    {
        if (getState()==7)
        {
            mwriteServer.println(strCmd);
            mwriteServer.flush();
        }
    }

    public String readAnswer()
    {
        String strBuf = "";
        try
        {
            if (getState()==7)
            {
                if (mbufServer.ready())
                {
                    strBuf += mbufServer.readLine() + "\n";
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error readAnswer : " + e.toString());
            return "";
        }
        return strBuf;
    }
}
```

In the main screen of the Applet I use the class as follows:

```
private tcp mtcpPaneel = new tcp();
mtcpPaneel.connectVri(getDocumentBase());
startListen(mtcpPaneel);
mtcpPaneel.sendCmd("REG ID");

private void startListen(final tcp tcpCon)
{
    Thread tListen = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        String strAnswer="";
        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (tcpCon.getState()==7)
                {
                    strAnswer = tcpCon.readAnswer();
                    //TODO : add strAnswer to string, and remove processed answer from this string
                }
                processAnswer(strAnswer);
                try {Thread.sleep(100);}
                catch (InterruptedException e){}
            }
        }
    });
    tListen.start();
}

private void processAnswer(String strAnswer)
{
    int intStart=-1;
    int intEnd=-1;
    String strStart  = "EG ID ";
    if (!strAnswer.isEmpty())
    {
        //find answer type
        intStart = strAnswer.indexOf(strStart);
        if (intStart>-1)
        {
            //remove start
            intEnd = strAnswer.indexOf('\n');
            if (intEnd==-1) intEnd = strAnswer.length();
            strAnswer = strAnswer.substring(intStart + strStart.length(), intEnd);
            //process answer
            processID(strAnswer);
        }
    }
}

private void processID(String strData)
{
    System.out.println("ID : " + strData);
}
```

When I open the Applet on my laptop I receive no data in the Java Console

But when I open the Applet on my computer I receive the requested ID information perfectly in the Java Console

Apparently Java upgraded their security so that I can't receive any data anymore from a remote port 6000.
Is there a work around so that I can receive the data again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem appears to be that the jar file is not signed, when i sign the jar file i do receive data again

apparently unsigned jar files had more access in java 7.65 and in java 8.25 the jar files have to be signed

I did the following to sign the jar file:

first create a keystore:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore myKeyStore -alias myName
keytool -selfcert -keystore myKeyStore -alias myName
```

then sign the jar file using the keystore i just created

```
jarsigner -keystore myKeyStore jarfile.jar myName
```

When I now load the Applet from any computer it is working fine again

some things to look into though (but thats another subject :)):

- jarsigner notifies me that the certificate will expire, and that I need to use -tsa or -tsacert to provide a timestamp
- before the Applet was running I had to click away some warnings about it being unsafe and to prevent it from being blocked